# ASP.NET MVC Web API does not generate Account View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm facing the following problem.

I have an **ASP.NET MVC with Web API** project and now I have to add users to the application, and for that I must modify the Identity so that the primary key is an `int` not a `string`.

In a simple MVC project there are created Account views but now in my **Views folder** there is no Account views and no way in the UI to register a user so I can use the Identity Framework.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please post some code !!

Comment: What do you mean by "In a simple MVC project there are created Account views but now in my Views folder there is no Account views.." ?

Comment: Yes that's the inconvnient part in beginning a project without including MVC and identity at start. If you're not too far away in development you can restart a new project and paste your work in in. The other option is to add all the files manually and that's is a pain.

Comment: When you create a ASP.NET Web Application with an MVC template in the Views folder there was generated another folder called Account in which there were all the views necessary to register a new User through the UI.Now my project is an ASP.NET Web Application with an Web API template, and I also included the MVC folders and core references

Comment: And also I don't have what code to post because my problem is not code related

Comment: @Mathieu: sadly I'm working on this project for four weeks now, and starting over is not an option

Comment: So add missing parts from an empty MVC project with identity is the way to go alas

Comment: @Mathieu: Ok, thanks!